# Very simple Javascript - trying to console.log an array of objects - not working?

Tags: javascript

Beginner here working with Javascript inside a script.js file in Visual Studio.

I wrote the following code to declare an array of objects and then console log the whole thing:

```
let frenchDictionary = [
    {
        "french": "qui",
        "english":"who"
    },
    {
        "french": "toujours",
        "english":"always"
    }
]

console.log(frenchDictionary)
```

But VS terminal throws the following error: frenchDictionary : The term 'frenchDictionary' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Why isn't it recognizing frenchDictionary as a variable?

Comment: how are you trying to run it?

Comment: This is more of a Visual Studio issue rather than a JavaScript issue. Update your question with the relevant Visual Studio tag.

Comment: Are you typing that directly into the terminal of VS? That wont work, because depending on your system that's either a CMD, PowerShell or something bash-like.  (from the error you quote, I suppose its a PowerShell terminal) None of them can run JS directly. You have to create a script file, where you put your script and then run this script using a runtime like NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to console log that from the PowerShell or something. Try typing this in the terminal:

```
node - NAME OF YOUR JAVASCRIPT FILE.js -
```